# How to copy image directly from Finder to the clipboard? (instead of opening with Preview)

Tags: finder, graphics, copy-paste

From Finder, how can I copy an image (in an image file, e.g., *.jpg, *.png) directly to the clipboard?
(as opposed to, e.g., opening the file in Finder and then `command + c` to copy it to the clipboard)

Answer (score 4):

After comments - it appears this may be a joint functionality of both the sending & **receiving** app.
Selecting the file only, then copy, will then correctly paste the image into Photoshop or Preview using the "New from Clipboard" in each case.
Pasting to Mail also works.

I initially didn't think this was possible, as Finder is not concerned at all with the contents of any file. If you copy, it will copy 'the file' as an entity, ready to paste elsewhere. To get the actual pictorial contents into the clipboard, you need an app that can first decode the file as an image, then specifically export its own clipboard when backgrounded - Preview is one such app

[It's looking more like the Finder copies this, but doesn't tell the user if they just look at the Show Clipboard window from Finder.]

…then I realised Quicklook incorporates the same functionality, so..

Select image file in Finder
Tap Spacebar to open in Quicklook.
Copy  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd> 
Switch to whichever app you need to paste the image.
Paste  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: FWIW... In **macOS Catalina**, simply selecting the _image file_  and pressing **⌘C**  then switch to the _application_ to paste the image using **⌘V** works without having to do anytime else. Note however, I've only tired this with built-in and **Apple** _applications_. Some _third-party applications_ may require an intermediate  step. --- Just tried in in LibreOffice and it works too.

Comment: Now that ***is*** interesting. It works to Photoshop too, in Mojave. I really never knew that.

Comment: Also, programmatically querying the clipboard after a **⌘C** on a _image file_ it clearly shows an _image object_ which can be used separate and apart from pasting the _image file_ as a _file_ elsewhere in the _file system_. So it's there and if the receiving _application_ has the ability, it obviously can take it as as _image_. (+1 for the QuickLook trick.)

Comment: mhm - the standard Finder 'show clipboard' shows only the file name… which isn't too useful :\

Comment: Programmatically querying the clipboard is not the same as the **Show Clipboard** _command_ in **Finder**. E.g: `{{«class furl», 76}, {«class icns», 935693}, {«class ut16», 82}, {«class utf8», 40}, {«class 8BPS», 1774090}, {GIF picture, 124244}, {«class jp2 », 213437}, {JPEG picture, 98488}, {TIFF picture, 4198020}, {«class PNGf», 533225}, {«class BMP », 4194358}, {«class TPIC», 1133665}, {Unicode text, 80}, {string, 40}}`

Comment: I guessed not - but how many users are going to know how to do that to find something like this? Let's call it a well-hidden functionality ;))

Comment: Nice!  This works for pasting an image into Google Docs.  (Curiously, it doesn't work for pasting into Roam Research in the browser or in the Roam desktop app (it pastes the filename instead), whereas a copy from Preview does work)

Comment: Yeah, as I was fumbling my way through this with the help of @user3439894 - it became apparent it needs complicity from sender and receiver.

Comment: After further examination, pressing **⌘C** from the **QuickLook** _window_, places the exact same _content_ on the clipboard as just **Finder** vs. e.g. opening the _image file_ in **Preview** and copying it. So while **Finder** makes it available on the clipboard as both an _image_ and a _file_, it is completely up to the _receiving application_ how it's going to handle what's on the clipboard and **QuickLook** is actually not a factor in this. (I'll leave the +1 anyway.)

Comment: The 'show clipboard' window specifies that it is displaying 'text' when it shows just the filename (default in this case). However, if you look using the Clipboard Viewer, then you will see 'public.tiff' amongst the various captured data types (similar to clipboard info). Preview (et al) likely use this to create new image documents. When creating a new image 'from clipboard' in Acorn, it is always 1024x1024 and ~4MB (32 bits per pixel, or ~'TIFF picture'). Maybe the Finder has particular defaults. When not using 'from clipboard, the resulting image matches the original.

Answer (score 1):

> How to copy image directly from Finder to the clipboard? (instead of opening with Preview)

Since using just **⌘C** on the selected *image file* in **Finder** does not make the contents of the *image file* available to **all** *applications* to paste into, the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* offered herein will work for those *applications* that it has to be just the content of the *image file* on the clipboard.

This adds a *keyboard shortcut* to **Finder** to place just the *content* of the selected *image file* on the clipboard, ready to paste into an application that supports pasting of the *content* of an *image file* when just **⌘C** does not work. This of course also works for applications that support **⌘C**.

Here is an *example* **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* used in **Finder** and assigned a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** of **⌃⌘C** that explicitly places the *content* of the *image file* to the clipboard, just as if opened in **Preview** and copied to the clipboard from there.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** and as an **Automator** *workflow* saved as a *Quick Action*  under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Create an **Automator** *workflow* as a *Quick Action* with settings **Workflow receives [image files] in [Finder]** and add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the *default code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property BMP : «class BMP »
property PNG : «class PNGf»
property GIF : GIF picture
property HEIC : TIFF picture
property JPG : JPEG picture
property TIFF : TIFF picture

set the clipboard to ""

tell application "Finder"
    set selectedImageFile to ¬
        item 1 of (selection as alias list)
    set nameExtension to ¬
        name extension of selectedImageFile
end tell

if nameExtension is "bmp" then
    set fileType to BMP
else if nameExtension is "png" then
    set fileType to PNG
else if nameExtension is "gif" then
    set fileType to GIF
else if nameExtension is "heic" then
    set fileType to TIFF
else if nameExtension is "jpg" then
    set fileType to JPG
else if nameExtension is "jpeg" then
    set fileType to JPG
else if nameExtension is "tiff" then
    set fileType to TIFF
else
    set msg to "This Automator Quick Action is not currently " & ¬
        "configured to handle the selected image file type."
    display dialog msg buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
        with icon 2 giving up after 5
    return
end if

set the clipboard to (read selectedImageFile as fileType)
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be expanded to handle additional *image file types* as needed. To ascertain the correct *class* to set a `property XYZ : ...` for, copy the opened *image file* to the clipboard, from e.g. **Preview**, and then in **Script Editor** run `clipboard info` and the first *class* it returns is what I'd use to extend the *example* **AppleScript** *code* adding a new `else if ...` *statement* to the current `if` *statement block*.

It will most likely be `TIFF picture`, however if this *class* is shown regardless of where in the *list* returned it is, it can be used as it will be of the highest quality *class* of what's offered for the copied opened *image file*.

---

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try macOS Finder Quick Action > Copy Image
Down this app. then config inside finder's extension

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1663442012

it support batch copy images file to clipboard not only the filename. Then easy paste to Figma
[image: Copy Image to clipboard not filename]
it also can batch convert images to .webp .avif format